# Boost::locale::as date format flags have no effect

Tags: boost, format, locale, flags

Here is the code snippet

```
std::wstring aResult;

boost::locale::generator gen;
std::locale::global(gen(""));

std::wostringstream output;
output.imbue(std::locale());

boost::locale::date_time aTime(x);

output << boost::locale::as::date_short << aTime;

aResult = output.str();
```

The problem is that the output always give the date format specified by locale and

- as::date_short
- as::date_long
- as::date_middle

always give identical results.

What can be the case here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably indicates your system has no/incomplete locale definitions.

E.g. this program:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wstring aResult;

    boost::locale::generator gen;
    std::locale::global(gen("C"));

    std::wcout.imbue(std::locale());

    boost::locale::date_time aTime;

    std::wcout << std::endl << boost::locale::as::date_full   << aTime;
    std::wcout << std::endl << boost::locale::as::date_short  << aTime;
    std::wcout << std::endl << boost::locale::as::date_medium << aTime;
}
```

Prints, on my Ubuntu box:

```
Thursday, June 5, 2014 3:06:27 PM
6/5/14 3:06:27 PM
Jun 5, 2014 3:06:27 PM
```

But **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9545fe0315e1a308)** (which runs on Debian) the same code prints:

```
Thu Jun  5 13:07:04 2014
Thu Jun  5 13:07:04 2014
Thu Jun  5 13:07:04 2014
```

Comment: That explains a lot! Thanks. There have been reported some bugs on locales on Mac OS. So will use Carbon library for this staff.